# Oracle 12.2: How can I get SQL*Plus or SQL Developer to prompt for user input on a variable?

Tags: oracle, variables, sqlplus, prompt

The script below will find and kill all sessions for a particular schema, and then drop the schema. It works perfectly, so I want to keep using it. However, I also want to allow the person running it to be prompted to input the schema name, as opposed to editing the code as it is currently set up.

I've tried ACCEPT, I've tried &&, and I can't quite seem to get it right.

Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE
  v_user_exists NUMBER;
  user_name CONSTANT varchar2(20) := 'FRED_2'; --this is where the user to delete is specified
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FOR c IN (SELECT s.sid, s.serial# FROM v$session s WHERE upper(s.username) = user_name)
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'alter system kill session ''' || c.sid || ',' || c.serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE';
    END LOOP;
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop user ' || user_name || ' cascade';
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF (SQLCODE = -1940) THEN
        NULL;
      ELSE
        RAISE;
      END IF;
    END;
    BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_user_exists FROM dba_users WHERE username = user_name;
      EXIT WHEN v_user_exists = 0;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already use PL/SQL, why would you do it in an anonymous PL/SQL block? Switch to a stored procedure and pass username as a **parameter**. Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure p_kill (par_username in varchar2)
is
  v_user_exists number
  user_name varchar2(20);
begin
  user_name := par_username;
  loop
    for c in ...
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Execute it (from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer) as

```
exec p_kill('FRED_2');
```

or - anywhere - as

```
begin
  exec p_kill('FRED_2');
end;
/
```

---

If you want to stick to current code, then `&` helps:

```
SQL> declare
  2    user_name varchar2(20) := '&user_name';
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('entered value = ' || user_name);
  5  end;
  6  /
Enter value for user_name: LITTLEFOOT
entered value = LITTLEFOOT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

`&&` is used when you reference the same substitution variable several times in the same code. For next execution (with a new value) you first have to `undefine` it.